# Parse query/procedure in Toad

Tags: oracle, toad

I am new to Oracle/Toad. I am trying to create new procedures using Toad as IDE. Don't have permission/access to execute the procedures in the Oracle DB. In order to check whether the procedure is written correctly wanted to parse the procedure. We have do have option in SSMS for Parsing the query.

Tried to find on Google and got Ctrl+F9 option. But nothing happens when i press those keys. Do I need to change any other setting along with it?
[SSMS Parse option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIVPM.jpg)

Comment: There is no relation to code or programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my point of view, what you are doing is pretty much useless. How are you supposed to write a program if you aren't allowed to execute it? Why don't you ask for access? Or, do as we do (here, on StackOverflow): someone asks a question, doesn't provide test case so we create it ourselves. You could do the same.

- if you have your own user in some database, do it there
- if you don't, consider installing Oracle XE
- if not, sign in for free access on apex.oracle.com and write code *online*

Though, what do you call "execute"? Can you *compile* it? That's what `create or replace procedure your_proc` does. `begin your_proc; end;` executes it.

As far as I can tell, you can tell TOAD to *format code* (Ctrl + Shift + F). If it fails, there's something wrong so you should fix it (TOAD will tell the position of the error). Other than that, if you can't compile nor execute it, I'd say that there's nothing you can do.

Comment: Agree to your comment...but work on client network where there are lots of restrictions ...only access we have is to select table :( . These procedures we are creating are to be used by third party ...just wanted to be sure that the procedures we are creating atleast compile...Will try Ctrl+Shift+F option. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome; unfortunately, those restrictions are quite ... well, *restrictive*. Good luck!

Comment: I'm glad if it helped.